# How to make better CSS ID rules

Tags: html, css

Im learning html + css and have question, it possible to write rules for several ID's, like what I have to reach my goal

```
<!-- language: lang-css-->

 #menu-item-207 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-207 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-206 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-206 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-205 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-205 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-204 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-204 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-203 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-203 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-202 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-202 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-201 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
 #menu-item-201 .menu-image-title:hover {
   color: #0095d1 !important;
 }
 #menu-item-200 .menu-image-title {
   color: black !important;
 }
```

How can i adapt it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ewww, why all the `!important`'s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use comma to combine several selectors:

```
 #menu-item-207 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-206 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-205 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-204 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-203 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-202 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-201 .menu-image-title,
 #menu-item-200 .menu-image-title {
    color: black !important; 
 }  
 #menu-item-207 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-206 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-205 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-204 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-203 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-202 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-201 .menu-image-title:hover,
 #menu-item-200 .menu-image-title:hover {
     color: #0095d1 !important; 
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use your `class`, you do not need your `ID`'s:

```
.menu-image-title{
   color: black !important; 
}

.menu-image-title:hover{
   color: #0095d1 !important;
}
```

You can use a `class` in more than one element at the same time.